# Should I use a default empty string or allow null value in Django fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I guess this question is very relevant outside Django ORM too. Since I am working on it, I will put it this way.

Say, I have a django model abstract class having the below field

`content = models.TextField()`

One inherited model definitely requires it and another takes it based on the choice (another field). I see there are two ways to go:

1. use `null=True, blank=True` in abstract class, make necessary conditional validation statements in inherited classes
2. use `default=''` in abstract class and make necessary conditional validation

There are two things I'd like to achieve here in this case

1. Form validation should be conditional
2. Database validation should be conditional

Which is more preferred approach? and Why not the other?

Answer (score 0):

From django docs:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that
>   means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty
>   string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for
>   “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.

You dont have to specify empty string for default because that is what django use for "no-data" anyway. Avoid null. I recommend you specify the field as blank=True (no null) and enforce your validation at form level.